# Three.js - Getting the low poly look

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d

I'm trying to generate some terrain in the low poly style, for reference, this kind of style:

[image]

What I mean by this is each triangle is one shade.

When I attempt something like this, the shading is very smooth. Here's an example with only a few triangles:

[image]
<sub>(source: [willdonohoe.com](http://www.willdonohoe.com/stackoverflow-images/smooth-shading.png))</sub>

I also tried adding shadows, but this didn't create the desired effect either. Here's a shot with more triangles with added shadows:

[image]
<sub>(source: [willdonohoe.com](http://www.willdonohoe.com/stackoverflow-images/added-shadows.png))</sub>

Looking through the Three documentation, the shading property on the materials class sounds like it would do the trick, but THREE.FlatShading and THREE.NoShading doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there a special technique that I need to use create this effect? Any direction you can point my way would be much appreciated.

You can find my first demo [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150103220858/http://www.willdonohoe.com:80/experiments/low-poly-terrain/shading.html)

Many thanks,

Will

Comment: you need unblended normal vectors on your geometry.

Comment: Hi @jAre, thanks for the reply. How do I go about creating unblended normal vectors? Google doesn't seem to tell me much about unblended normals. Sorry my 3D knowledge is fairly limited. I'm using this project as a learning activity.

Comment: It's simply when normal vectors are perpendicular to the polygon and not smoothed.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_group

Comment: To get the desired vectors, you need to overwrite the vertex normals of your geometry with the face normals. So what you need to do is iterate through all of your geometry's faces and copy over the face normal to every vertex normal vector.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for your replies. If one of you write this as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: This answer was outdated. Updating:

`material.shading = THREE.FlatShading` is now `material.flatShading = true`.

You modified the vertex positions of your `PlaneGeometry`.

To generate flat shading with `MeshLambertMaterial`, you must update your normals by calling

```
geometry.computeFlatVertexNormals();
```

For other materials, simply setting `material.flatShading = true` is sufficient to get the flat look.

three.js r.87

Comment: but wouldn't computeVertexNormals() not interpolate the normal vectors and as it is named, you would get a smooth shading, which is not what the question was about? The second part of your answer seems confusing to me.

Comment: @GuyGood The first part of my answer is the answer to the question. The second part of my answer I added just for comparison purposes.

Comment: Can you explain how to use `THREE.FlatShading`? It's not explained in the question or this answer.

Comment: @Luke Updated answer. Unfortunately, this issue is a bit complicated due to the fact that all materials do not behave the same in this regard.

Comment: I got it working with `new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ blending: THREE.NoBlending, flatShading: true });` in r87. If I switch to `MeshLambertMaterial` the triangles show up blurred again.